# React router 4, reference param inside route defintion

Tags: reactjs, parameters, routes, react-router

I have a nested route definition with react router 4

```
const App = () => (
<Switch>
  <Route
    key={3}
    path='/case-studies'
    render={({ match: { url } }) => (
      <div>
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${url}/`}
          render={(location) => <Page
            location={location}
            data={
              {
                type: 'archive',
                api: apiBase + '/' + 'pages' + '?slug=case_study'
              }
            } />
          } />
        <Route
          exact
          path={`${url}/:slug`}
          render={(location, match) => <Page
            location={location}
            data={
              {
                type: 'archive',
                api: apiBase + '/' + 'case_study' + '?slug=' + match.params.slug
              }
            } />
          } />
      </div>
    )}
  />,
```

I'm interested in this line:

```
api: apiBase + '/' + 'case_study' + '?slug=' + match.params.slug
```

I know how to reference match within my rendered component 'Page' props.
However I'm trying to define this property ('api') within the route and pass it through, already defined, to the component, but with the dynamic paramter slug.

However I can't seem to access match here, or its dynamic property 'slug' (inside the route definition).

Is this possible?
If so, since I haven't found any reference to it elsewhere, is it an anti-pattern? (if so, why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
<Route
  exact path={`${url}/:slug`}
  render={({ match: { params: { slug } } }) => (
    <Page
      data={
        {
          type: 'archive',
          api: apiBase + '/' + 'case_study' + '?slug=' + slug
        }
      }
    />)
  }
/>
```